# pytest How to locate input file for conftest.py in test directory when run test from parent directory

Tags: pytest

In tests directory has 2 sub-directories such as tests/api and tests/sanity. Note tests/api has conftest.py that expects to find input.conf in tests/api directory. Note running tests from tests/api works fine. But run test from parent directory tests, it failed with:
py.test --test_option=input.conf
Usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]

py.test: error: no such option: --test_option

Can someone please shows how I can structure my test so this would work? 
I also tried specify the test directory such as the following but it cannot find input.conf.
py.test --test_option=input.conf api/test_api.py

E       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.conf'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your syntax is correct (you are I think transposing the name and extension of the file) you just need to specify the location of the file correctly including relative or absolute path:

Instead of:

```
py.test --test_option=input.conf
```

do:

```
py.test --test_option=api/input.conf
```

Comment: Great. This worked. py.test --test_option=api/input.conf api/test_api.py .One follow up question is if I have multiple directories that contains tests and each one has their own input.conf file and I want to run all of them. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but you need to change a program a little bit. Take a look at these file/directory functions http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories and accept the answer if you are happy with it (or ask as many Python questions as you wish :-) )